# What is the most efficient way to call PHP methods from within another machine under the same hub?

Tags: php, curl, rpc

Implementing a REST api for mobile app.

At the server end, Server A is calling procedures at Server B.

Found that the most expensive cost is not computing within Server A or Server B (which takes less than 10ms), but the network cost during the remote procedure call between A and B (which takes more than 100ms).

Using [rmccue Requests](https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub%2Ecom%2Frmccue%2FRequests&ei=fGhAVdU_o6GaBe_igNAL&usg=AFQjCNHnif99xuhDXsNR6UGwoU5-vaMhNA) to do the network request (underlying is [curl_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php)()).

So, which would be an more efficient alternative in calling PHP methods from within another machine under the same hub?

Comment: why not take a look at SLIM Framework , super easy to implement http://www.slimframework.com

Comment: @Satya SLIM doesn't say that it's efficient in PHP RPC.

Comment: I didn't say that SLIM is efficient in PHP RPC, however, it is quite efficient in REST calls.